# Compiler optimize error - Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

In a library project im releasing, it have the -optimize=true set as a compiler option, this works fine in Flash Builder 4 and Flex Builder 3, but gives the following error in Flash Builder 4.5

Encountered errors or warnings while building project inControlPlatformLibrary.as.
    configuration variable 'compiler.optimize' must only be set once

Any ideas?

Using Flex 3.2

Comment: +1 for specifying the version of Flex you were using.